# Toastify React, error when attempting to use

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When ever I attempt importing tosify into react:

Using the following:

import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify'; import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

I get the following error:

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/react-toastify/dist/react-toastify.esm.mjs
Can't import the named export 'cloneElement' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Not sure what solution is and have spent alot time trying to find solution but I am unable too, if anything else is needed let me know but when the tosify import not there the site works fine.

Comment: I deleted nod_modules and package-lock.json and run 'yarn' instead. Everything worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by updating my node version and react version,

> npm install --save react@latest
> npm install -g npm-check-updates
> npm audit fix --force

Answer (score 16):

Try by changing the version to older version of toastify. Manually add this in your package.json file "react-toastify": "^8.1.0", , and then run npm i then again run npm start.

Answer (score 9):

As stated in this [bug report](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify/issues/775), this seems to be an issue that appears when `react-toastify` is used with older versions of `react-scripts`.

Your options are:

- upgrade to the newest version of `react-scripts` (version 5 or above)
- downgrade `react-toastify` to version `9.0.3`, which [seems to still work](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify/issues/775#issuecomment-1150715526) with older versions of `react-scripts`

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is this

```
npm i react-toastify@9.0.3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue in `React 18.2.0`, which was fixed by:

```
#upgrading to the latest version of react-scripts
npm install react-scripts@5.0.1  # OR npm install --save react-scripts@latest

#if you encounter errors after upgrading.
rm -r node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some kind of error because of node version. Could you try to reproduce this with latest node version?
Don't forget to remove node_modules and yarn.lock | package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I have tried to update my yarn , and react versions , but the problem was still there.
the best way is to downgrade toastify version to 8.0.0, and it will work.

- use this command:

  ```
  npm i react-toastify@8.0.0
  ```
- or: if you are using yarn

  ```
  yarn add react-toastify@8.0.0
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this as import `import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';`